# jquery Syntax error illegal character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I keep receiving error of illegal character in firebugs

```
 $('#service_chk').click(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.is(':checked')) {
         $('#service').css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​
     } else {
         $('#service').css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'none');​​​​​​
     }
 });
```

Error keep pointing "coma" in $('#service').css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'block');​​​​​​

and this is my view

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="service_chk"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="service" style="display:none;"></td>
</tr>
```

Im on the way learning javascript, please help me, thanks.

Comment: Code seems issueless. Try to use show/hide instead.

Comment: no error in my console.

Comment: the are some "hidden" characters in your javascript code. copy javascripy to notepad and remove those characters!

Comment: see jsfiddel here https://jsfiddle.net/1LxxswL9/

Comment: $('#service_chk').click(function () {
      $('#service').css({'display': $(this).is(':checked') ? 'block' : 'none'});
 });

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue is because of encoding in your text editor or the IDE which you are using. Copy paste your script into jsfiddle and you'll see the errors.[image]

**HTML**

```
        <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="service_chk">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="service" style="display:none;">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1655/

Comment: how it is not visible here in this site ?

Comment: @Mahi Maybe because of stripping the characters when posting a question.

Comment: why he can't able to see in his own editor then ? alien came to our planet ?

Comment: @Mahi Because the text editor and the aliens might not be highlighting the syntax error unlike jsfiddle.

Comment: Im using sublime text, should I change my text editor ? anyway thanks man. @KK

Comment: @NasihunAminSuhardiyan Don't change it. Just make sure if you are copying something, it doens't have any encoding issue or change the encoding settings for sublime.

Comment: I had this isuue after Filezilla's transfer. In this case choose: transfer -> transfer mode -> BINARY

Answer (score 0):

you have a bunch of invisible spaces (zero width spaces) in your code.

below is the fixed version of your code:

```js
 $('#service_chk').click(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.is(':checked')) {
         $('#service').css('display','block');
     } else {
         $('#service').css('display','none');
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="service_chk"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="service" style="display:none;"></td>
</tr>
```